# Does anyone want Ukraine to be called "the Ukraine"?

Tags: terminology, ukraine

According to the Wikipedia article [Name of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_Ukraine#.22Ukraine.22_versus_.22the_Ukraine.22), Ukrainians prefer the English term to be "Ukraine" rather than "the Ukraine".

Do any governments, such as Russia, or other political groups want Ukraine to still be called "the Ukraine" in English, akin to the Gdansk/Danzig dispute on the English language Wikipedia?

Comment: In German it is called "die Ukraine", even though most countries are refereed to without an article. In French, articles are used or not depending on the grammatical context just like every country. I am afraid it's more a language quesiton than a political one. Also, Gdańsk and Danzig have always been the respectively Polish and German names for that city, back then when it was ~94% German and still now that it is 100% Polish. The city didn't have "it's name changed", contrary to what you might think at 1st approach, it just had it's country changed.

Comment: However it is true that today Gdańsk is usually refered to the outside world (except German speaking word) by it's Polish Name, and before 1945 it was referred to by it's German name. What I meant is that Germans and Poles never changed the name they use to they refer to the city.

Comment: @Bregalad: German uses the article with country names when they don’t have neutral grammatical gender (or are plural). So it’s _der Iran_, _der Tschad_, _die Schweiz_, _die Slowakei_, _die Ukraine_, _die Vereinigten Staaten_, _die Vereinigten Arabischen Emirate_. (Sometimes there are regional/dialectal/individual differences, e.g. _Iran_ is sometimes considered neutral.)

Comment: Apparently I would love to listen people calling "India" as "The India".

Comment: Not sure if it is political and not english language question

Comment: It is incorrect , but I don't take offense about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There can be multiple answers on this question.

**Official position** of Ukraine is: ["Embassy **of Ukraine** in the United States of America"](http://usa.mfa.gov.ua/en). Other official entities follow the same pattern.

Here's how ["The Telegraph" puts it](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destinations/europe/ukraine/articles/amazing-fact-you-probably-didnt-know-about-ukraine/):

> **7. It’s not *The* Ukraine**
>
> The English-speaking world commonly referred to the country as The Ukraine. That is, until independence in 1991 when the West gradually dropped the definite article. In 1993 the Ukranian government requested that the country be called just Ukraine. US ambassador William Taylor, who knew that addition of the “the” was considered insulting by some Ukrainians, said it implied a disregard for the country’s sovereignty.

**Average people in Ukraine**. Unfortunately, there is no preference among Ukrainians. The main reason is probably due to the fact that many of us don't speak English well enough to see any difference on using the definite article with toponyms. Sad but true.

The level of foreign language competency in Russia is not better than in Ukraine (to say the least), so I don't think there are big enough communities there who would advocate using or omitting "the" when calling other states.

Neither Russian nor Ukrainian language has articles at all.

---

However, **calling Ukraine by Russians** has yet another notable issue.
In both Russian and Ukrainian languages, there are two ways to tell location: "in" and "on". According to grammar rules, "in" is used for state names, while "on" is for landmarks, territories, islands, etc. For example, "on Ural", "on the river(-side)", "on the North".

> A vivid example: "**on** Cuba" means "island", while "**in** Cuba" means the name of the country. However, quite often they use "on" even in this case.

Russians tend to **call countries that they have occupied or plan to occupy like they were lands**, not countries. So the Russian government tends to say, "**on** Ukraine", not "in Ukraine".

Comment: "в Кубе" is totally wrong. And besides, it coincides with the math term.

Comment: @Anixx Say what?

Comment: @Anixx - "V Kubinskoy respublike" :)

Comment: Lol, what? The "в" and "на" preposition cannot be translated as "in" and "on" directly. We say "на Украине" but this must be translated as "in Ukraine".

Comment: "Russians tend to call countries that they have occupied or plan to occupy like they were lands, not countries" - if that would be true, then constructions like "на Польше" (occupied in the end of XIX century, so at least that period's literature would have it like that), "на Якутии" or "на Сибири" would be valid, but that's not the case, unless you would argue all of those are sovereign states now (or were in that period of occupation, in case of Poland or Finland, for example). Only the regions with geographical designations are called ike that (the North, the Far East...).

Comment: The in English is usually in reference to a union or collections. hence, the Falkland Islands or the United Kingdom. We are no longer part of the Soviet Union and are a sovereign country.

Comment: @PavelMayorov 
you don't say на россии do you?  на also is used for islands so На Гавайях for on Hawaii. Ukraine however, is not a territory or island and в Украине should be used here.

Comment: _"...many of us don't speak English well enough to see any difference on using the definite article with toponyms. Sad but true."_ There's nothing sad about that. English is certainly the most common language used internationally, but it's quite normal and reasonable that many people living at some distance from English-speaking countries would not speak it, especially if there happens to be a different language in the region historically more useful as a second language.